# How to achieve onChange functionality in radio button

Tags: reactjs

I have two radio buttons inside RadioGroup. Please see the below code:

```js
<RadioGroup name="condition" selectedValue={this.state.condition}>
  <div className="col-md-12 radio">
    <Radio value="auto" />Automatic CR
  </div>
  <div className="col-md-12 radio">
    <Radio value="manual" onChange={this.onAutomaticClick}/>manual CR
  </div>
</RadioGroup>
```

When a user wants to switch from `manual CR` to `automatic CR`, I want to show a modal popup such that if a user clicks on `Yes`, then switch should happen, and if he clicks `No`, then user should remain inside `manual CR` only.

With the code I have tried, `onChange` event itself not firing. Can anyone please guide me on this. And also how can we stop switching radio buttons on condition. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't say what `<RadioGroup>` you're using, but, for example, MUI's `onChange` hangs on the `<RadioGroup>` (as opposed to individual radio buttons), which makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the Material-UI, your onChange handler should be on the parent component(RadioGroup), if you want to display a warning before making any change, you could trigger the warning in the onChange of RadioGroup and make the value changes only if you get any positive confirmation from the user.